# jackson: fasterxml or codehaus

Tags: mule

Can someone pls clarify, what version of jackson is used by Mule v 3.8 and where?
The [official documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/json-module-reference) is confusing. First, it's referencing to the fasterxml maven repository. But later on the same page an example creates an object with org.codehaus.jackson.Mapper.

So, what version of the Mapper shall be actually used: codehaus or fasterxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule uses `codehaus` package for `json modules` and the codehaus version used is `1.9.11` in [`Mule 3.8`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.8.x/pom.xml)